# How can I exclude rows that exceed the accumulative sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple query which is below:

```
SELECT fam1 Fam2,
       dim,
       quantit_pr_vue,
       quantit_restante,
       d_signation_2,
       longueur,
       largeur,
       d_signation_1,
       d_cors,
       face,
       nuance
FROM   hel
GROUP  BY fam1,
          fam2,
          dim,
          quantit_pr_vue,
          quantit_restante,
          d_signation_2,
          longueur,
          largeur,
          d_signation_1,
          d_cors,
          face,
          nuance
ORDER  BY fam2,
          longueur,
          nuance;
```

The result is below :

```
Fam2    Dim Quantit_pr_vue  Quantit_restante    D_signation_2   Longueur    Largeur D_signation_1   D_cors  FACE    NUANCE
ST1 296 25  25  ST MDF 2F KEN02321 280X210X18 SUP LIG   280 210 SM 2F KENNY 02321 296 SUP LIG   FONCE   2F  1
ST1 296 50  50  ST MDF 2F KEN02321 280X210X18 SUP LIG   280 210 SM 2F KENNY 02321 296 SUP LIG   FONCE   2F  1
ST1 296 100 100 ST MDF 2F KEN02321 280X210X18 SUP LIG   280 210 SM 2F KENNY 02321 296 SUP LIG   FONCE   2F  1
ST1 296 150 150 ST MDF 2F BALANCE 280X210X18 SUPER LIGHT    280 210 SM 2F BALANCE 296 SUPER LIGHT   BALANCE 2F  4
ST1 296 300 300 ST MDF 2F BALANCE 280X210X18 SUPER LIGHT    280 210 SM 2F BALANCE 296 SUPER LIGHT   BALANCE 2F  4
```

[image]

I want to exclude the last row which has `Quantit_restante = 300` because when summing it to the previous records, it exceeds 500.

The screenshot only shows only a group which is `Fam2 =ST1`, `Dim=296`, `Logueur=280`, `Largeur =210`, `FACE = 2F`.

Comment: Which column(s) provide the perceived ordering in the rolling sum of `Quantit_restante` ?

Comment: The one I mentioned in the ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY Fam2, Longueur, NUANCE 
The screenshot only shows a group which is Fam2 =ST1, Dim=296, Logueur=280, Largeur =210, FACE = 2F. I updated the question.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data. See the help center for more on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also by applying to a rolling total.

> ```
> SELECT 
>  [Fam2], 
>  [Dim], 
>  [Quantit_pr_vue], 
>  [Quantit_restante],
>  [D_signation_2], 
>  [Longueur], 
>  [Largeur], 
>  [D_signation_1], 
>  [D_cors], 
>  [FACE], 
>  [NUANCE]
> FROM [hel] AS h
> CROSS APPLY (
>     SELECT SUM(Quantit_restante) AS RollingTotal
>     FROM [hel] h2
>     WHERE h2.Fam2 = h.Fam2
>       AND h2.Dim = h.Dim
>       AND h2.Longueur = h.Longueur
>       AND h2.Largeur = h.Largeur
>       AND h2.FACE = FACE
>       AND h2.Quantit_restante <= h.Quantit_restante
> ) ca
> WHERE Fam2 = 'ST1' 
>   AND Dim = 296
>   AND Longueur = 280
>   AND Largeur = 210
>   AND FACE = '2F'
>   AND RollingTotal <= 500
> ORDER BY Fam2, Dim, Longueur, Largeur, FACE, Quantit_restante;
> ```
>
> ```
> Fam2 | Dim | Quantit_pr_vue | Quantit_restante | D_signation_2                            | Longueur | Largeur | D_signation_1                 | D_cors  | FACE | NUANCE
> :--- | --: | -------------: | ---------------: | :--------------------------------------- | -------: | ------: | :---------------------------- | :------ | :--- | -----:
> ST1  | 296 |             25 |               25 | ST MDF 2F KEN02321 280X210X18 SUP LIG    |      280 |     210 | SM 2F KENNY 02321 296 SUP LIG | FONCE   | 2F   |      1
> ST1  | 296 |             50 |               50 | ST MDF 2F KEN02321 280X210X18 SUP LIG    |      280 |     210 | SM 2F KENNY 02321 296 SUP LIG | FONCE   | 2F   |      1
> ST1  | 296 |            100 |              100 | ST MDF 2F KEN02321 280X210X18 SUP LIG    |      280 |     210 | SM 2F KENNY 02321 296 SUP LIG | FONCE   | 2F   |      1
> ST1  | 296 |            150 |              150 | ST MDF 2F BALANCE 280X210X18 SUPER LIGHT |      280 |     210 | SM 2F BALANCE 296 SUPER LIGHT | BALANCE | 2F   |      4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=436ff345eb6d9ac2241abd5b021dcc72)*

Answer (score 3):

You can use window function `SUM()` to get the running total and exclude the rows that the running total exceeds 500:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(Quantit_restante) OVER (ORDER BY Fam2) total
  FROM [dbo].[hel]
) t
WHERE total <= 500
ORDER BY Fam2;
```

Comment: This solution is a lot more efficient than the previous solution using `CROSS APPLY`